# Gerenciar urls em um sistema

Tags: node.js

Estou em um projeto onde há o ambiente de teste, e o ambiente de produção.

Quando estou desenvolvendo em teste, utilizo algumas urls diferentes para isso. Utilizo alguns serviços da amazon, e que são diferentes das urls de produção.

Entretando, é muito chato ficar manualmente, trocando as urls, gostaria de saber se há alguma boa prática para gerenciar isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes verificar dentro da aplicação qual o ambiente, ou seja se estás em produção ou desenvolvimento.

Com o express seria algo assim:

```
var app = express();
if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
    // setar variáveis de produção
} else {
    // setar variáveis de desenvolvimento
}
```

Em Node.js nativo seria:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // setar variáveis de produção
} else {
    // setar variáveis de desenvolvimento
}
```

Comment: Esse `app.get('env')`. De onde vem isso ? Como eu faço pra ele saber que é produçao ? @Sergio

Comment: @Jonathan O `app.get('env')` é API do express.js e esse método retorna o ambiente em que a aplicação está a correr. Por norma é "development" mas se estiver setado o ambiente de produção ele retorna "production".

Comment: Acha certo dentro do `if` eu fazer um `var config = require('./config1');` e no `else` fazer `var config = require('./config2');` ? Ou seja, deixar no if, a responsabilidade de realizar um require.